# How to get the original value from the resultant value

Tags: javascript, math

I am having the following problem and a result is got from it how can i get back the original value from the answer.

```
count = 5000;  rate = 5%
deduction_percentage  =  5 / 100 (rate / 100)
deduction_percentage = 0.05;
weight deduction = 5000 * 0.05 (count * deduction_percentage) 
weight_dedcution = 250
total = 5000 - 250 (count - weight_deduction)
total = 4750
```

with this answer 4750 and rate 5% how can i get the original count as 5000.

Comment: java AND javascript? pick one, the two languages are vastly different - hint, the answer is 95% (100 - 5) of the original

Comment: x*(100-5)% = 4750; x*(95/100)=4750; x = (4750*100)/95;

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This is an arithmetic question having nothing to do with programming. `4750 * 100 / 95 --> 5000 `

Comment: You learn Algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var count = 5000;  var rate = 5; // 5%
var deduction_percentage  =  5 / 100;  //(rate / 100)
deduction_percentage = 0.05;
var weight_deduction = 5000 * 0.05;  //(count * deduction_percentage) 
weight_dedcution = 250;
var total = 5000 - 250; // (count - weight_deduction)
total = 4750;

// below line to get back original count.
var original_count = total * 100 / (100 - rate);
console.log(original_count);
```